# jquery 'form.valid' not supported error IE

Tags: jquery

On my MVC project I have a Login page that works perfectly in Chrome, but in IE (11) I get the following error:

> SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support property or method 'valid'

This is my code:

```
if (!$('#formLogin').valid()) {
   return false;
}
```

I'm using jquery 1.11.1

The Login form:

```
<form id="formLogin" data-bind="submit: login">
   <label>User ID</label>
   <input class="required email form-control" type="text" data-bind="value: loginUserName" name="loginUserName" />

   <label>Password</label>
   <input class="required form-control" type="password" data-bind="value: loginPassword" name="loginPassword" />

   <button type="submit" class="btn-orange" id="buttonLogin" data-bind="visible: showLoginButton">Log In</button> 
   <button data-bind="click: logout, visible: showLogoutButton" class="btn-orange" id="buttonLogout">Log Out</button>
</form>
```

Any idea what can causes it?

Comment: Try inspecting the value of `$('formLogin')` using `console.log` and the developer console.

Comment: @Owen can you explain what will that help me?

Comment: @user3378165 Using console: http://vaso.hu/programming/console/, and before your condition add it: `console.log($('#formLogin'));`

Comment: @karacsi_maci Could you explain how will it help me?

Comment: Because you can see, is your object is exists.

Comment: Anyway, can you show us your form please?

Comment: @karacsi_maci I did it and got an object, do you want me to post it?

Comment: no, it means, object is exists, so that is not the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue by upgrading the version of jquery.validation through `Package Manager Console`:

```
PM> Install-Package jQuery.Validation
```

Answer (score 0):

When checking only one element, I use length instead of valid()

```
if ($('#formLogin').length==0) {
    return false;
}
```